# Problem with factorials: find the least n for which (n + 16)!(n+20)! ends with a number of zeros divisible by 2016

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, factorial

I have been working on this problem during the last few days but I can't find a good solution.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is that the number of zeros is the power to which $10$ is raised, which is the lesser of the power to which $5$ or $2$ is raised.

Comment: You say that you "have been working on this problem during the last few days."  During those few days, what have you tried?  Do you have any thoughts on this problem other than the problem's statement?

Comment: I know that if I need for example 2016 zeros I must have at least a factor $5^{2016}$. I can rewrite it as $(n+20)(n+19)(n+18)(n+17)((n+16)!)^2$. Then I tried to find a number $n$ such that, dividing it by raising powers of $5$, I can get the maximum exponent of  5 into $n!$. However i didn't find it very useful. (I'm sorry if my English is bad but I don't live in an Anglo-Saxon country)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of zeros ended $n!$ gives formula

$$p = \left[\frac{n}{5^1}\right] + \left[\frac{n}{5^2}\right]+... + \left[\frac{n}{5^k}\right]$$
At first check $n=4040$:

$$\left[\frac{4040}{5^1}\right] + \left[\frac{4040}{5^2}\right]+ \left[\frac{4040}{5^3}\right]+ \left[\frac{4040}{5^4}\right]+ \left[\frac{4040}{5^5}\right]=808+161+32+6+1=1008$$
and $n+4=4044$:

$$\left[\frac{4044}{5^1}\right] + \left[\frac{4044}{5^2}\right]+ \left[\frac{4044}{5^3}\right]+ \left[\frac{4044}{5^4}\right]+ \left[\frac{4044}{5^5}\right]=808+161+32+6+1=1008.$$
For $n=4024$ product $(n+16)!\cdot (n+20)!=4040!\cdot 4044!$ ends with a 2016  zeros

Comment: Thank you very much! Did you work by trial and error or is there a better way to calculate n without doing lots of operations? I ask you that because I can't use any calculator to solve problems like that.

Comment: @J.Zago unfortunately i don't know universal method for solving. One more idea to use formula geometric progression, but the first element of this progression is not known and common ratio near 5, but not right 5.